# How to present and refer to a paper that has been finished, and reviewed by almost all coauthors but not submitted?

Tags: application, conference

I finished a paper with my Master's thesis advisor and some other colleagues in January of this year, but we have essentially been waiting on a professor from another university who contributed to the paper to review it and for some reason they seem to not have time to do so (3 pairs of eyes have already looked over the paper).

I am currently in the process of applying for a grant for a conference and I was wondering how to list the paper among the "publications and educational accomplishments" section. The paper is essentially ready for submission but has yet to be submitted.

My questions are:

1. Should I just list this as a "draft" or is there a better way to
   refer to it to convey that we are just waiting on the approval of
   one person but it is essentially finished?
2. Since everything is typed up and ready for submission, would it
   be helpful to include the link to the finished document in the
   application?

Comment: In cases like this recalcitrant co-advisor, I have sent emails like "Please send me any comments within two weeks, or we will assume you are OK with the contents of the paper." May help you get this out, good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there's not really any way to list a paper as "It's done, except for one professor who won't get around to reading it."

Papers are usually listed as 1) published, 2) accepted, 3) in review, 4) in submission, and 5) in preparation.

Some people, including myself, find *(4) in submission* meaningless because the journal hasn't even accepted it for review. This paper is "in preparation," nothing else.

Yes, if you have permission to share the paper (e.g. it's already on *arXiv) then feel free to link that in your materials.

Comment: I mostly agree, but I think OP could add some phrase to say that we expect to submit it very soon, especially if it is their only item to list in that section.

Comment: It's not the only item to list. I have an REU paper, as well as a scholarship and research award but this is the most serious paper I have completed to date.

Comment: @toby544 Meh. What's "very soon"? Why does that matter? It just seems like CV-padding. Just list it as "in prep," that is a perfectly fine place to be.

Comment: OK. If it is the best or most serious, then I would add some phrase like I suggested. The link will be useful too.

Comment: @toby544 Feel free to post an answer as well.

Comment: I don't have much to say. Your answer and comments are good.